# Subaccount selector for user field

Tags: acumatica

I have added a user field to the Non-Stock Items screen that I want to hold a subaccount selection selected via a selector that works the same way as the other standard subaccount fields on that screen.   When looking at source DAC for the other SubAccount fields, there is an attribute for [SubAccount...] that works in a way that I don't really understand.  I also have an Account user field that uses a standard PXSelector lookup to the Account table (that works properly).

I've added a modified version of the attribute I found on the other SubAccount fields as follows:

```
[SubAccount(typeof(InventoryItemExt.usrCOGSAccount), DisplayName = "COGS Subaccount", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible, DescriptionField = typeof(Sub.description))]
```

Where InventoryItemExt.usrCOGSAccount is my user field which holds the Account ID from the lookup on that user field.

However, when I use this, I get an error on rendering the screen (index outside the bounds of the array).

Bottom line:  Is there a way I can make this Subaccount user field have a lookup just like the other Subaccount fields, with the F3 on each segment working independently?

Comment: What happens if you just make it [SubAccount(DisplayName = "COGS Subaccount")]. FYI just in case it is confusing to the user, there is already a COGS account/sub on inventory item (InventoryItem: COGSAcctID, COGSSubID)

Comment: Nope - same error:  "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: Can you include any stack trace? it almost doesnt seem related. If you remove the attribute entirely from the field just making it a [PXDBInt] do you get the same error?

Comment: No - in fact, if I use a standard PXselector attribute selecting from the Sub DAC, it works fine - although it selects the entire subaccount.  I want it to work the same way the others do, selecting segments...

Comment: what does your page entry for this look like? the same as the other account fields. I think its mask edit vs pxselect. We have account/sub fields on the same dac/page and it works fine so i know its possible.

Comment: So - are you saying I can use the [SubAccount...] attribute as it's used on the other Subaccount fields?  Not sure what you mean by 'Page Entry'...   I mean, sure - it's obvious that you're doing exactly that with the other subaccount fields on that page - so if I'm using exactly the same attribute, why doesn't it work for me?

Comment: Yes you can use it as its declared on the other sub account fields. you are also adding the field to the aspx page. Is it the same setup as the other sub account fields in the aspx page file? I think it should be a maskedit but i would have to check